# How to add padding to a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, padding

I could not find a way to do this with `UIView`, as I depict in the following picture:
It portrays having a image background with a shadow.
Is there anything of the shelf for padding, or do I need to add more child objects to achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: so why not doing the same as with the background picture, take the frame for the image, add 10 to x and y origin coordinates and update width and height ?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think so. The image is set using `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageWithShadow.png"]];`.
So the frame of the image is the frame of the view.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that this can't be done with any methods/automatically.

Comment: I think so too, I think you'll have to compute the frame manually

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be pretty straightforward to do, but you'll have to implement it yourself.

If I understand your question correctly you'd like to have a padding value added automatically to your subviews - for example, pass an X/Y value of `0, 0` for a button's frame, but have its *actual* position be `10, 10`.

I haven't fully fleshed this out, but you'd probably need to create a `UIView` subclass that had two extra bits - firstly, a 'padding' property (probably a `UIEdgeInset`), and then override the `setFrame` setter to automatically add the correct amount of padding to a frame. You could, say, have an `initWithFrame:padding:` method to create objects. You could even have your UIView subclass automatically query the superview to obtain the padding.

There's a lot of scope here - so I guess to answer your question, *no* - *there isn't anything off the shelf* - but implementing it yourself is pretty achievable and probably quite fun as well!

(assuming you find doing this sort of thing fun, of course...)

Comment: I came to this need because I am tired of adding/subtracting magic number values to x, y, widths, heights in CGRect/frame's in order to properly place items with complex looking views, like the one I exposed here. Subclassing seems to be a good approach to the problem.

Comment: BTW, the right type would be `UIEdgeInsets` (with "s" at the end).